# How to save pandas dataframe after click streamlit button?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I write a page in streamlit with button "Generate csv".

In code I have a pandas dataframe which is rendered in main page. I want to generate it to csv after click button.

I found on official forum answer how to do that, but It's not working in my example even if it's same.

[https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/saving-a-dataframe/677][1]

My code:

```
if len(data_frame) == 0:
    st.write("Please load file.")
else:
    min = st.number_input('Od:', 0, len(data_frame), 0)
    max = st.number_input('Do:', 0, len(data_frame), len(data_frame) )
    dataset = st.container()
    table = st.dataframe(data_frame.iloc[min:max])

    if st.button('Generate csv'):
        open('table', 'w').write(table.to_csv())
```

So as u can see the code is same as in example on forum. I also tried to create funtion in main script and call it from streamlit:

```
def generate_csv(df):
    
    df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

And in both examples I got

> StreamlitAPIException: to_csv() is not a valid Streamlit command

After click button, csv should be save on server.

Streamlit docs is poor and I can't found resolve for that example. Maybe someone had same problem and have solution?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, [`st.dataframe()`](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html#streamlit.dataframe) is intended to ***display** a dataframe as an interactive table*.

You should not use that object (here called `table`) to call `to_csv()`, but instead use the original `pd.DataFrame` object (here called `data_frame`).

Update your code with the following:

```py
if len(data_frame) == 0:
    st.write("Please load file.")
else:
    min = st.number_input('Od:', 0, len(data_frame), 0)
    max = st.number_input('Do:', 0, len(data_frame), len(data_frame) )
    dataset = st.container()
    table = st.dataframe(data_frame.iloc[min:max])

    if st.button('Generate csv'):
        generate_csv(data_frame.iloc[min:max])  # <-- see change
```